# window.print not printing correctly in Opera, but print preview then file->print works flawlessly; using print css

Tags: css, image, printing, opera, print-preview

Unlike a few other articles, this is not an issue with window.print() not working in Opera.  It does work.  Whether I navigate to File->Print or call window.print(), a print dialog box opens.  The problem is the output is not correct.  Specifically, an image is supposed to print out but only a piece of it is printed.  This is only happening in Opera.  If I use window.print(), the above problem occurs.  If I use File->Print, again, the same problem occurs.  However, if I turn on Opera's Print Preview option, then File->Print, it prints out the image flawlessly.  I don't get it.

FYI, (important), I'm using a separate stylesheet for printing.

Thank you very much.

**UPDATE**

I did find a line in the print stylesheet that is having a great affect on this problem:

```
html { background-color : #FFFFFF; }
```

When not commented out, the output displays in the Print Preview.  Then, I do File->Print and it prints out correctly.  But it does not print after initiating window.print().

When commented out, the output does not display in the print preview.  Then, I do File->Print and it does not print out correctly or at all.  But it does print after initiation window.print().

I'm not sure what to do from here.

**UPDATE 2**

Here is a simplified version of the code that still does not print correctly from File-> Print, but it prints correctly with Print Preview.  It should print 3 pages, but File->Print only prints the first page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
      #Content {
        height: 250px;
        width: 25%;
        overflow-y: auto;
      }
    </style>

    <style type="text/css" media="print">
      #Content {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>    
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="Content">
      <img src="http://i00.i.aliimg.com/photo/v0/247580968/GPS_software_GPS_schematic_diagram.jpg" /><br />
      <img src="http://i00.i.aliimg.com/photo/v0/247580968/GPS_software_GPS_schematic_diagram.jpg" /><br />
      <img src="http://i00.i.aliimg.com/photo/v0/247580968/GPS_software_GPS_schematic_diagram.jpg" />
    </div> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Does anybody have any suggestions, solutions, or workarounds to this problem?  Anything at all would be really appreciated, even if it's not exactly the right answer.